# Python Socket Connection to networked computer

Tags: sockets, python-2.7, networking

I'm working on a simple chat program to send data back and forth between multiple computers that are on the same network (this isn't meant for use outside of the LAN). The program works when both the server and client are on the same computer (using localhost), but fails when I try to move the client application over to another computer connected by the same router. I'm currently testing this on my home network.

If I port forward (for port 5000 to IP 192.168.1.100) and change the server_host to the public IP rather than the server's local IP (192.168.1.100 - determined from ifconfig in comp's terminal) it works just fine. So, my question is: can I connect to the machine using just its local IP rather than port forward/public IP when the client is on another computer within the same LAN? The reason I ask is because this would be preferable than asking permission to open ports where I hope to use this program.

Simplified Server Code:

```
from socket import *

host = '192.168.1.100' #This is the local IP of this particular machine
port = 5000
s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((host, port))
s.listen(5)

while True:
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    print 'Server Connected by: ' + str(addr)
    while True:
        data = conn.recv(1024)
        if not data: break
        conn.send('Data: ' + str(data))
    conn.close()
```

Simplified Client Code:

```
from socket import *
server_host = '192.168.1.100' #If I change this to public IP/port forward it works
server_port = 5000

msg = 'Hello!'
s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((server_host, server_port))
s.send(msg)
data = s.recv(1024)
print str(data)
s.close()
```

I cannot post pictures because of my lack of 'reputation' points: but here's the cli output when I connect via changing my server_host to my public IP and port forwarding:

Client side: Data Received: Data: Hello!                                                                                                                                                                   Server: Server Connected by: ('192.168.1.1', 61004)

And here is what I get when I just try to use the local IP of the server (192.168.1.100):

Client (pauses for awhile and then): [errno 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond                                                                                                                                                                Server: (Nothing shows up on server side)

Comment: Did you try to communicate Within your machine ??? By running both client and server in your machine ??

Comment: Yes - I am able to communicate when both the server and client are on the same machine. The problem occurs when I try to communicate when the server and client are on different computers, even though they are on the same network.